# Write a custom PlaceholderResolver in Spring (like PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver)

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I am using MBeans in an web application for application properties which a lot of people normally put in property files. The MBeans will be written and read from a database for persistence.

**I am looking for a way of exposing my application properties (from the (m)beans to Spring (e.g. Spring EL, applicationContext.xml). In a lot of applications the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver is used but since I am only having a regular (m)Bean I want to expose the bean properties to spring expression language.**

I have looked at PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerResolver to see how the properties are exposed to Spring Expression Language, but I don't see how.

I think somehow I need to write a custom PlaceholderResolver which accesses my MBeans. I have been googleing now for hours, so I would appreciate a hint :)

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with MBeans, but our application is getting application settings out of a database and then using them in our application context. We are just extending [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) and then you just need to call the `setPropertySources()` method. In our constructor, we have something like this:

```
MutablePropertySources propertySources = new MutablePropertySources();
Map<String, Object> propertiesFromDB = getPropertiesFromDB();
MapPropertySource propertySource = new MapPropertySource("propsFromDB", propertiesFromDB);
propertySources.addFirst(propertySource);
setPropertySources(propertySources);
```